# Is it generally understood that tech recruitment emails are constantly sent out?

Tags: job-offer, united-kingdom, tech-industry

I'm a web developer, and I get usually 2-3 recruiter emails a day regarding various positions. Some are good/relevant offerings, and some seem to fall in the category of "this guy has worked with computers, so he's clearly relevant for this laboratory technician role".

Sometimes I'd like to share funny/bad/irrelevant offers I get emailed through, but I fear it could lead people to believe I'm secretly looking for another job.

Is it generally understood in the tech industry that job offer emails don't indicate that somebody is looking for a job, or should I just refrain from sharing?

Comment: I get so many, I almost missed one that was useful (current job)

Comment: I have a separate email address for job-search related things, and usually I just don't look at it. Problem solved.

Comment: I once got an email from a recruiter, sending me the details of a job that _I was hiring for!_

Comment: @Benubird: Did you take it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I applied, but when I interviewed myself I decided I wasn't suitable for the position :p

Comment: @Benubird: That must have been a tough pill to swallow ^_^

Comment: If I don't receive one every hour I get lonely...jk

Comment: If someone decided to share one of these amusing things with me I'd reply 'Stop effing around sending me spam and do some b...dy work." Then I'd start thinking about filtering the company mail.

Comment: @Benubird otherwise you would have just hired yourself and cut out the middleman. "If you want a job done right, you have to do it yourself."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would say it's pretty darn commonplace. Personally, I would think a direct report posting a ridiculous offer would indicate they are either not shopping, shopping and totally oblivious, or shopping and don't care who knows it. I would expect that I know which category that person is likely in.

If you want to make it crystal clear, you could start the post with something like

> I constantly get unsolicited job ads and some of them are outrageously out of touch. Here's a great example...

Comment: In the past I've usually prefaced it with something like "I got this random job offer email the other day..." or something similar.

Comment: Alternatively, "Check out this recruiter spam" - which is both a common phrase I've heard, and conveys the idea that it's "spam" and therefore unwanted

Answer (score 1):

The recruiter sends out a spam email based on a database of names/emails/phone. They maximize their search by using few keywords then sending it to a blanket user. The idea is that a few will come back and some might say, "No thanks, I'm only interested in X" Then they update their database with X and continue on. Basically the less you talk to them the less you'll get. The more you respond or reply, the more emails/calls you'll get.

It appears these recruiting agencies got bots crawling various websites and building a huge database of names/emails and so on that they share with themselves. As a joke, I once forward all emails to a friend and from that moment on they'd call me but ask if my friend is there.

Just a note, I still get recruiter calls from when I applied to Monster nearly 10 years ago and used my parent's home phone number. Occasionally they'd get a call but it's like once or twice a year, now, but they still call.